# Two Problems on Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I've two questions which I'm not getting where to start with.

$1^{st}$ Question:

> Consider two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ having
>   probability density functions uniform in the interval $[−1, 1]$. What
>   is The probability that $X^2+Y^2\gt1$ ?

$2^{nd}$ Question:

> What is the value of $\lambda$ such that $Pr(X\gt mean\{X\})=\frac{1}{e}$, where *pdf* of $X$ is $p_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x},\ x\geq0,\ λ\gt0$ ?

Here I'm not sure whether the $mean\{X\}$ represents expectation $E(X)$ or not.

Answer (score 2):

(1) $$f\left( x,y \right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4},~-1<x<1,~-1<y<1.$$
    then $$P\left( {{X}^{2}}+{{Y}^{2}}>1 \right)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left( area \right)=1-\frac{\pi }{4}.$$

[image]

(2)
$E(X)=1/\lambda $
$$P\left( X>\frac{1}{\lambda } \right)=\frac{1}{e}\Rightarrow \underset{\frac{1}{\lambda }}{\overset{\infty }{\mathop \int }}\,\lambda {{e}^{-\lambda x}}dx=\frac{1}{e}$$ for every $(0<\lambda<\infty)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(x,y)$ here ?

Comment: You got two variables, X and Y.

Comment: He means the joint density function. The individual PDFs are independent so you multiply to get the joint.

Answer (score 0):

**First question:** Draw the square in which our joint density function lives. It is easier to find the probability that $X^2+Y^2\le 1$.

This is the part of the square that lies within the unit circle. The circle has area $\pi$, the square has area $4$, so the probability that $X^2+Y^2\le 1$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Thus the desired probability is $1-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

**Second question:** Probably by mean they mean $E(X)$. This is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. The probability that $X\gt t$ is $e^{-\lambda t}$. If $t=\frac{1}{\lambda}$, this is $e^{-1}$. Note that the result is independent of $\lambda$. So trick question, any $\lambda\gt 0$ has the required property.